# How to extract substring from directory name using bash

Tags: windows, bash, file

I have a group of directories with the following name template:

[random combination of numbers and/or characters and/or symbols(including blank space)]+[single space]+[(]+[number]+[)].

E.g. 
`asdf%k123 test1 (12345)`
`foo(123)??bar (456)`
`324(asd)! (456)`
`random()123 (456)`

How do I go about extracting only the number within parenthesis using bash commands (without '()')? Keep in mind that number within parenthesis might occur in the random part of name, but I only need the on at the end. In any case every name will end with [space][(][number][)].

Comment: Given a name of `asdf%k123 test1 (12345)` (as per your example) is your expected result `12345` ?... and lets say you have `foo(123)??bar(456)789 quux (54321)` is your expected result `54321`? I suggest you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60305563/edit) your question to provide several examples of source names and the expected result for each one.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I was a bit ambiguous. And yes, I only need the number in the last pair of ().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Get the number

You can get the last number with `sed`:

`sed 's/.*(\([0-9]*\))$/\1/' <<< "asdf%k123 test1 (12345)"`

> 12345

The `sed` script is written like this:

- the beginning `s` means this performs a substitution, which uses the following syntax `s/pattern/replacement/`
- the `/` character defines the separator for substitution, you can use any character but `/` is a very common one
- `.*(\([0-9]*\))$` is the pattern (I will get back to it later)
- `\1` is the replacement, in this case it replaces the first string captured by the pattern, which is the number (see below)

The key element is the pattern. In this case `.*(\([0-9]*\))$` could be split as:

- `.*` which matches any character any number of times
- `(` which matches the opening brace character
- `\([0-9]*\)` which captures any string composed by digits, a.k.a. a number
- `)` which matches the closing brace character
- `$` which matches the end of the line

In the capture pattern, i.e. `(\([0-9]*\)`, it should be noted that `\(` and `\)` are the delimiters for capturing and should not be mistaken with `(` and `)` which are regular parentheses characters.

TL;DR: this pattern says “I want to capture a number surrounded by parentheses just before the end of the line”. And the `sed` script says “I want to print exclusively the number that was captured”.

### List directories

You can parse the directories using `find`. If you just want the first level subfolders:

`find /path/to/dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d`

The `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` options ensures that you only get children of 1 depth, while the `-type d` option lists only the directories (not files, not symbolic links, etc.).

You can get more depths by replacing `-maxdepth 1` with the number of your choice, or simply omit this option to get all subfolders recursively.

Since your directories seem to have all sort of special characters, I would also suggest to get them with the `-print0` option which separate the result with a null character `\0` instead of a newline.

### Solution

All in all it would look like this:

```
find /path/to/dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' dirname
  do
    sed 's/.*(\([0-9]*\))$/\1/' <<< $dirname
  done
```

If you want to filter out the directories that do *not* match your pattern, you may change sed to use the `-n` option and then print with the `p` command:

```
find /path/to/dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' dirname
  do
    sed -n 's/.*(\([0-9]*\))$/\1/p' <<< $dirname
  done
```

Comment: Not having much experience with powershell I keep getting errors when trying to run this. 'Missing statement body in do loop' and 'Missing file specification after redirection operator'. Probably some stupid mistake on my side tho :/

Comment: unquoted `$dirname` is what causing troubles imo.

Comment: @Bjergsen I thought your issue was about bash, now you are mentioning PowerShell. Which one are you using exactly?

Comment: I wasn't thinking when typing that sorry. I'm using Cygwin to run bash scripts.

Comment: @Bjergsen Bash from Cygwin is fine. It’s just that when you mention PowerShell it looks like you are trying to run PowerShell script.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following;

```
pat='[[:blank:]]\(([[:digit:]]+)\)/$'   # regex pattern explained below
path="."                                # or specify to the path where the directories exist
for d in "$path"/*/; do                 # pick directories in the $path
    if [[ $d =~ $pat ]]; then           # if the directory name matches the pattern
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"       # then print the extracted number
    fi
done
```

Result with the provided examples:

```
456
12345
456
456
```

The regex pattern `[[:blank:]]\(([[:digit:]]+)\)/$` matches a substring such as:

- a space `[[:blank:]]`
- followed by a left paren `\(`
- followed by a sequence of one or more digits `([[:digit:]]+)`
- followed by a right paren `\)`
- followed by a slash (meaning it is a directory) `/`
- and the end of string `$`

The sequence of digits is surrounded by parens so the matched
portion is captured and assigned to the bash variable `BASH_REMATCH`.

Comment: I've copied the code to bash file, placed it in the containing folder, but when i run it i get these errors:  


`$bash test.sh
test.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
test.sh: line 7: `done'`

Comment: If you are running the code under Windows environment by using a Windows text editor, you may have a wrong line endings not <LF> but <CR><LF>. If so, please try [dos2unix](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/) to correct the issue.

Comment: I'm using Cygwin environment, so I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Even with Cygwin, the ending code <CR><LF> may cause a problem depending on the bash version. Is it possible to apply `od` or other binary dump tool to check the ending code of your bash script file?